# Indy/Open SSL not firing OnVerifyPeer event

Tags: delphi, openssl, indy, indy10

We're using Open SSL 1.0.2.14 with a PKCS12 certificate to secure a TIdHTTPServer.  it connects securely and works well in every way except one.  it won't fire the OnVerifyPeer event.

I wonder if that's because the certificate is self-signed?  (That's all I've been given.)

```
  iohSSL.SSLOptions.KeyFile:='C:\Users\Mike\AppData\Local\cert.pfx';
  iohSSL.SSLOptions.CertFile:='C:\Users\Mike\AppData\Local\cert.pfx';

object iohSSL: TIdServerIOHandlerSSLOpenSSL
  OnStatus = iohSSLStatus
  SSLOptions.Method = sslvSSLv23
  SSLOptions.SSLVersions = [sslvSSLv2, sslvSSLv3, sslvTLSv1, sslvTLSv1_1, sslvTLSv1_2]
  SSLOptions.Mode = sslmServer
  SSLOptions.VerifyMode = [sslvrfPeer]
  SSLOptions.VerifyDepth = 0
  OnStatusInfo = iohSSLStatusInfo
  OnStatusInfoEx = iohSSLStatusInfoEx
  OnGetPasswordEx = iohSSLGetPasswordEx
  OnVerifyPeer = iohSSLVerifyPeer
  Left = 256
  Top = 120
end
object srv: TIdHTTPServer
  Bindings = <
    item
      IP = '127.0.0.1'
      Port = 5500
    end>
  DefaultPort = 5500
  IOHandler = iohSSL
  MaxConnections = 25
  KeepAlive = True
  ServerSoftware = 'Mike'
  OnQuerySSLPort = srvQuerySSLPort
  OnCreatePostStream = srvCreatePostStream
  OnDoneWithPostStream = srvDoneWithPostStream
  OnCommandGet = srvCommandGet
  Left = 183
  Top = 118
end
```

Here's a log of activities:

```
StatusInfo:  SSL status: "before/accept initialization"
StatusInfoEx:  type=Handshake Start  msg=before/accept initialization
StatusInfo:  SSL status: "before/accept initialization"
StatusInfoEx:  type=Accept Loop  msg=before/accept initialization
StatusInfo:  SSL status: "SSLv3 read client hello A"
StatusInfoEx:  type=Accept Loop  msg=SSLv3 read client hello A
StatusInfo:  SSL status: "SSLv3 write server hello A"
StatusInfoEx:  type=Accept Loop  msg=SSLv3 write server hello A
StatusInfo:  SSL status: "SSLv3 write certificate A"
StatusInfoEx:  type=Accept Loop  msg=SSLv3 write certificate A
StatusInfo:  SSL status: "SSLv3 write certificate request A"
StatusInfoEx:  type=Accept Loop  msg=SSLv3 write certificate request A
StatusInfo:  SSL status: "SSLv3 flush data"
StatusInfoEx:  type=Accept Loop  msg=SSLv3 flush data
StatusInfo:  SSL status: "SSLv3 read client certificate A"
StatusInfoEx:  type=Accept Loop  msg=SSLv3 read client certificate A
StatusInfo:  SSL status: "SSLv3 read client key exchange A"
StatusInfoEx:  type=Accept Loop  msg=SSLv3 read client key exchange A
StatusInfo:  SSL status: "SSLv3 read certificate verify A"
StatusInfoEx:  type=Accept Loop  msg=SSLv3 read certificate verify A
StatusInfo:  SSL status: "SSLv3 read finished A"
StatusInfoEx:  type=Accept Loop  msg=SSLv3 read finished A
StatusInfo:  SSL status: "SSLv3 write session ticket A"
StatusInfoEx:  type=Accept Loop  msg=SSLv3 write session ticket A
StatusInfo:  SSL status: "SSLv3 write change cipher spec A"
StatusInfoEx:  type=Accept Loop  msg=SSLv3 write change cipher spec A
StatusInfo:  SSL status: "SSLv3 write finished A"
StatusInfoEx:  type=Accept Loop  msg=SSLv3 write finished A
StatusInfo:  SSL status: "SSLv3 flush data"
StatusInfoEx:  type=Accept Loop  msg=SSLv3 flush data
StatusInfo:  SSL status: "SSL negotiation finished successfully"
StatusInfoEx:  type=Handshake Done  msg=SSL negotiation finished successfully
StatusInfo:  SSL status: "SSL negotiation finished successfully"
StatusInfoEx:  type=Accept Exit  msg=SSL negotiation finished successfully
StatusInfo:  SSL status: "SSL negotiation finished successfully"
StatusInfoEx:  type=warning Write Alert  msg=close notify
```

I spent time using the debugger but it's not at all clear whether Indy or OpenSSL is choosing not to verify peer.  I think it may be OpenSSL.

Why is OnVerifyPeer not firing?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Offhand, everything looks fine to me. I don't see anything that should be preventing `OnVerifyPeer` from firing. So, you are just going to have to debug into Indy's code, make sure the IOHandler's internal `TIdSSLContext` is assigning the private `VerifyCallback` function to, and enabling the `SSL_VERIFY_PEER` flag on, the underlying OpenSSL `SSL_CTX`.

Comment: Thank you, Remy!  It's called with SSL_VERIFY_PEER and SSL_VERIFY_FAIL_IF_NO_PEER_CERT.  SSL_CTX's verify_mode is correctly set to 3 and default_verify_callback is assigned to IdSSLOpenSSL.VerifyCallback and yet IdSSLOpenSSL.VerifyCallback never fires (I put a breakpoint there).  verify_depth I have provided is 0.  I suspect this must mean there's something wrong/incompatible with the certificate messing with OpenSSL. Delphi 10.4, Indy 10.6.2.0.  Any other ideas?

Comment: I have no idea. You should ask the OpenSSL community.